# Laravel Basic Routing with no parameters - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I have a custom route controller that checks the database before returning view. that being said I'm not passing any parameters to this controller besides the first and never will. Is there a way to stop laravel from expecting a parameter? I'm getting this error:

`mydomain/login` ---- Works Fine

`mydomain/login/sometext` -- Throws error

> "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException"
>    /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function(){return View::make('main.landing');});
Route::get('/{path}', array('uses' => 'RouteController@index'));
```

Then in my RouteController I take $path and query database to check if route exists and then displays the custom view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Please post your routes definitions.

Comment: Just did. Thanks Bogdan.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify to the router that you want to allow slashes in your route parameter. You can do it like so:

```
Route::get('/{path}', array('uses' => 'RouteController@index'))->where('path', '(.*)');
```

This will allow any character.

Comment: Nice! Works great. Saved the day Bogdan. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

By default route parameters do not accept slashes. You need to explicitly allow any characters in your *path* parameter:

```php
Route::get('/{path}', array('uses' => 'RouteController@index'))
    ->where('path', '(.*)');
```